# Integer's specific (Java Core)

Tags: java

i've got this question on interview:

```
public Integer v1 = 127;
public Integer v2 = 127;
public Integer v3 = 513;
public Integer v4 = 513;

public void operatorEquals(){
    if (v1==v2)
        System.out.println("v1 == v2");
    else throw new RuntimeException("v1 != v2");
    if (v3==v4)
        System.out.println("v3 == v4");
    else throw new RuntimeException("v3 != v4");
}

**Result**: java.lang.RuntimeException: **v3 != v4**
```

Can you explain: why? I have no suggestions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java `Integer` objects are cached until 127, but not above.

The effect of this is very similar to how the [String interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) works, so all `Integer` objects with values in the range [-128;127] are the same **instances** too -- returning true with referential equality check too, (e.g. `==`), not only using `.equals()`.

**EDIT from Arnaud Denoyelle**

From **Integer.java** :

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    assert IntegerCache.high >= 127;
    if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't sigh _that_ much.

Comment: Can you explain more detailed... ?

Comment: I edited to show the code of `Integer#valueOf()`. As you can see, between IntegerCache.low (-128) and IntegerCache.high (+127), you actually don't create a new Integer.

Comment: @user2171669 Maybe you also have a look at String interning explained here http://javatechniques.com/blog/string-equality-and-interning/

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle thanks, though I must say it feels a bit strange to get edited while editing the question myself

Comment: Thk you guys, and this Q is for Junior :)

Answer (score 4):

This is the defined behaviour for Java when Autoboxing. Check the relevant [Java Language Specification section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7). Read the discussion section there also. The following paragraph is taken from the specification:

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127 (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.
>
> Ideally, boxing a given primitive value p, would always yield an
>   identical reference. In practice, this may not be feasible using
>   existing implementation techniques. The rules above are a pragmatic
>   compromise. The final clause above requires that certain common values
>   always be boxed into indistinguishable objects. The implementation may
>   cache these, lazily or eagerly. For other values, this formulation
>   disallows any assumptions about the identity of the boxed values on
>   the programmer's part. This would allow (but not require) sharing of
>   some or all of these references.
>
> This ensures that in most common cases, the behavior will be the
>   desired one, without imposing an undue performance penalty, especially
>   on small devices. Less memory-limited implementations might, for
>   example, cache all char and short values, as well as int and long
>   values in the range of -32K to +32K.

For ints, those between -128 and 127 (inclusive) autoboxed Integer objects will return true for the check ==. It is said that these integers are cached and in a constant pool.
But if you just do `new Integer(int)` the objects created will always be different.